# Sql and html form connection using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have recently  created a form and tried connecting it to a sql database. 
The code was able to execute but I dont see the data inserted in the table. Kindly help.
I have 6 columns but I only want to insert data in first two columns to test.

Here is the PHP code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['firstname'])) {$fname=$_POST['fname'];}
if(isset($_POST['lastname'])) {$lname=$_POST['lname'];}
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "user_login";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
else{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare ("INSERT into user(First_Name,Last_Name,mail,password,confirm password,date_of_birth) values(?,?,"","","","")");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$firstname,$lastname);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "registration successful";
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();



}
```

Comment: Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` after `<?php`, then you will see what goes wrong.

Comment: `USER` is a special word in mySQL - you perhaps should use backticks around it

Comment: Check your line where you create your INSERT statement. You have double quotes inside a double quoted string. Either quote the sql statement with single quotes, or change the double quotes inside the statements to single quotes.

Comment: Also `confirm password` cannot be like that. Either rename the column to remove the space, or enclose it in backticks.

Comment: Come to think of it, no need to store the `confirm password` data anyways, it should be exactly the same as `password` (and when you do insert data there, *please* properly hash it).

Comment: You can't connect your code to the database server through phpMyAdmin, what you've done here, and indeed what should be done, is to connect directly from your PHP application to the database server itself. phpMyAdmin is a graphical application to help administrators manage a MySQL/MariaDB instance, it's not an API that your application can access to federate access to the database.